# Reuse for `EventLoopGroup`

Tags: netty

Guys would you consider it as a good strategy 
to try and reuse threads behind `nioEventLoopGroup`
for server with a lot of connect/disconnect scenarios ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be dependent on what you mean by "reuse". However in general the [EventLoopGroup](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/EventLoopGroup.html) threads are used for I/O. One important characteristic of NIO (and may asynchronous networking stacks) is that it is designed to handle many I/O operations with a relatively small set of threads. If you start using the I/O threads for "time consuming" operations then you will take away from the time those I/O threads could be spending on I/O. If you have "time consuming" tasks (i.e. blocking tasks, expensive computations, etc...) you may want to consider dispatching these to an alternative [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Comment: The scenario is more connecting to some peers for short time and force disconnect, for each peer we use completelly new EventLoopGroup, can we improve it somehow?

Comment: Why you are using a "new EventLoopGroup"?  In general there is nothing wrong with sharing event loops for different [Bootstrap](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/bootstrap/Bootstrap.html) or even [ServerBootstrap](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.html).

Comment: Please post back with your status so others may know if this was helpful or what you ended up doing.